# Add element on List + Showing the index of this List

Tags: python

```
list1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]
```

1. i've needed to add element "7000" after the [6000]
2. also how to show the index of the value of 40

Comment: please show the exact output after insertion

Comment: 1. output = [5000, 6000, 7000]
2. shows the index of the value of 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list.insert` and `list.index`

```
list1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]
print(list1)

list1[2][2].insert(2, 7000)  
print(list1)

print(list1.index(40))
```

```
[10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]
[10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, 7000], 500], 30, 40]
4
```